# Lighttpd: Redirect Domain but not Subdomain

Tags: redirect, subdomain, lighttpd

In the past I had the following config on Lighted that would allow me to redirect some secondary domains I own to my primary domain.

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "superdomain\.net|superdomain\.eu" {
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://mything.com/" )
}
```

This works fine. If someone tries to go to `superdomain.net` he'll be redirected to `http://mything.com` also keeping full URL query.

However, today I was trying to setup the sub-domain `webmail.superdomain.net` and Lighted matches `webmail.superdomain.net` on the rule before and redirects the user to `http://mything.com`.

The config for the subdomain was:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "webmail.superdomain.net" {
    var.domain = "webmail.superdomain.net"
    include "/var/webconfig/config/template/domain-generic.conf"
}
```

I place that rule before the other one but still no luck. Is there a way I can change the first rule to only match a domain and not subdomains?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I just found the answer!** My redirect rule should be:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^superdomain\.net$|^superdomain\.eu$" {
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://mything.com/" )
}
```

Added `^` at the begging of each domain and `$` at the end to specify the start and end of the string to match. This way subdomains aren't matched.